# Google Drive API: Downloading a file in Java

Tags: java, google-drive-api

So using Google Drive's API, I am trying to download a file from my drive account. I have followed Google's quickstart guide (https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/java) and used Google's DriveQuickStart.java to initialize the Drive object.

Everything with the object works correctly (i.e acquiring all the files from my google drive account and displaying their IDs and titles); however, when I tried downloading a file through the input stream of the function Google developed, I keep getting a null exception error.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
 private static InputStream downloadFile(Drive service, File file) {
        if (file.getDownloadUrl() != null && file.getDownloadUrl().length() > 0) {
            try {
                HttpResponse resp =
                        service.getRequestFactory().buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(file.getDownloadUrl()))
                                .execute();
                return resp.getContent();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // An error occurred.
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            // The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that when the method calls file.getDownloadURL(), it returns a null value. According to the documentation, it should return a null value if the file I am trying to download is a native Google Drive file; however, the file that I am downloading is simply a jar file, so it can't be because of the file extension (I also tried it on other formats too).

Why is it returning a null value, and what can I do to resolve this issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out.

For anyone else who struggled with this, the answer is really simple:
In the DriveQuickStart.java code, pay attention to this part:

```
    /** Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart. */
private static final List<String> SCOPES =
    Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);
```

And make sure you set it to:

```
    /** Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart. */
private static final List<String> SCOPES =
    Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE);
```

So the only reason why it didn't work was because program did not have the appropriate permission to do so.